# Read CSV and put the same exact contents in new CSV using PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm currently using the following code to open a CSV file, and write the contents to a new file.

```
<?php
// File to be written
$wFile = 'file.csv';     // Write file
$oFile = 'file_new.csv'; // Original file

// Chmod the file to be sure
chmod($wFile, 0777);

// Open the new file 
$fp = fopen( $wFile, 'w');

// Open the original file
if( ($handle = fopen($oFile, "r") ) !== FALSE )
{
    // Walk through the file and write it to a new file
    while( ($data = fgetcsv( $handle , 1024, ";") ) !== FALSE )
    {
        fputcsv($fp, $data, ';'); // Write
    }

    // Close
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Everything works, except for one thing. When i RAW view the csv, the column headers are as following in the original file:

> SKU;name;PE;SDR;PP;code;category;Wasserdruck bar;"Gasdruck
>   bar";Path;image (img.jpg, img2,jpg);D * d;d1 * d2;d-R(p);d;Preis Ä./St¸ck;Kg.;D (mm);d (mm);L (mm);L1 (mm);H (mm);"Max. Reperatur 
>   durchmesser ÿ";Karton;VPE;Typ;Steel Nominal DN;K (mm);"D
>   (mm)";"D2
>   (mm)";n  ad;Remarks;Remarks 2;Aanbeveling supplementen

The created CSV has the first row (column headers) as following:

> SKU;name;PE;SDR;PP;code;category;"Wasserdruck bar";"Gasdruck
>   bar";Path;"image (img.jpg, img2,jpg)";"D * d";"d1 * d2";d-R(p);d;"Preis �./St�ck";Kg.;"D (mm)";"d (mm)";"L (mm)";"L1 (mm)";"H (mm)";"Max. Reperatur 
>   durchmesser �";Karton;VPE;Typ;"Steel Nominal DN";"K (mm)";"D
>   (mm)";"D2
>   (mm)";"n  ad";Remarks;"Remarks 2";"Aanbeveling supplementen"

As you can see, some special characters go wrong, but that's not very important. The main problem (i think) is that fputcsv puts quotes around the table header columns.

In the second example you can see there's quotes around "aanbeveling supplementen", where in the original there are no quotes around this column..

I hope somebody can help me out, thanks in advance :)

PS: What I'm trying to achieve is to replace the image column, I have already written a script that replaces the image urls and it works now, except for this problem..

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
fputcsv($fp, $data, ';', '');
```

instead of:

```
fputcsv($fp, $data, ';');
```

See the PHP documentation for the fputcsv function: https://www.php.net/fputcsv

The 4th parameter ($enclosure) defaults to '"', which is why the column values are surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [copy function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.copy.php) and test if the result is correct.